# Meteor 0.7.0 hangs with mongodb initialization

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Recently updated to Meteor 0.7.0, and when I try to run the app with

```
meteor run
```

It hangs on:

```
Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
```

I assume, the local db got borked. How can you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `meteor reset` before you do `meteor run`.

Try also deleting the directory in `.meteor/local/db`

Sometimes it does take a while to initialize give it 5 minutes.

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with the 0.7 release as well: "Meteor 0.7.0.1: Fix failure to initialize local MongoDB server."